# How to read the SD Card ID number?

Tags: android, c++, windows, mfc, sd-card

How can I programatically read the SD Card's CID register, which contains a Serial Number and other information?   Can I do it through Android Java, or Native code?

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 13):

Here is sample code for getting SID and CID

```
if (isExteranlStorageAvailable()) {
    try {
        File input = new File("/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc1");
        String cid_directory = null;
        int i = 0;
        File[] sid = input.listFiles();

        for (i = 0; i < sid.length; i++) {
            if (sid[i].toString().contains("mmc1:")) {
                cid_directory = sid[i].toString();
                String SID = (String) sid[i].toString().subSequence(
                        cid_directory.length() - 4,
                        cid_directory.length());
                Log.d(TAG, " SID of MMC = " + SID);
                break;
            }
        }
        BufferedReader CID = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                cid_directory + "/cid"));
        String sd_cid = CID.readLine();
        Log.d(TAG, "CID of the MMC = " + sd_cid);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CID_APP", "Can not read SD-card cid");
    }

} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "External Storage Not available!!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: THanks for giving nice example for fetching data from any of the device without any other constraint.....

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing? Is `/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc1` something we can rely on across manufacturers? What will this code do if there is more than one microSD card, e.g. one embedded and one removable?

Comment: just read the code you can understand what code is doing. we can not reply on this completely, it was for Android 2.x versions not it might have changed. so according to that we need to modify the code.

Comment: I can see what the code is actually doing, but what I meant was, what is its intent? E.g. what is "SID" supposed to signify? It's not a standard term for SD cards, as far is I can tell. It's not the serial number, nor the CID register, nor the OEM ID. I tried this approach via adb shell on a new device, and it works, except that I don't know whether mmc1, mmc2, or mmc0 reflect the removable SD card.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to find my SD card CID by plugging my phone to my computer via usb and using the adb tool (Android SDK)

```
$ adb shell
# cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/../../cid
```

My phone is rooted so I'm not sure if this is accessible on non-rooted phones.

Also try

```
$ adb shell
# cd /sys/block/mmcblk0/../../
# ls
block                 fwrev                 preferred_erase_size
cid                   hwrev                 scr
csd                   manfid                serial
date                  name                  subsystem
driver                oemid                 type
erase_size            power                 uevent
```

These are explained in the kernel documentation http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/mmc/mmc-dev-attrs.txt

Comment: I tried this on non-rooted phones (Huawei, Sony, Motorola) with no problems. So I'd say it doesn't require a rooted phone.

Answer (score 5):

The only code I've found thus far to provide the id is C++ or C#
http://jo0ls-dotnet-stuff.blogspot.com/2008/12/read-secure-digital-sd-card-serial.html

http://jo0ls-dotnet-stuff.blogspot.com/2008/12/read-cid-and-csd-c-implementation.html

If you are a C++ developer you may be able to take this and make it work on Android.

Answer (score 5):

I made this one... it worked for me... hope it makes u clear!

```
String getSDCARDiD()
    {
        try {

            File file = new File("/sys/block/mmcblk1");
            if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {

                memBlk = "mmcblk1";
            } else {
                //System.out.println("not a directory");
                memBlk = "mmcblk0";
            }

            Process cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /sys/block/"+memBlk+"/device/cid");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmd.getInputStream()));
            sd_cid = br.readLine();
            //System.out.println(sd_cid);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sd_cid;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

As BMB wrote, you cannot know the real path of the SD card in the /sys filesystem. However, /sys implements aliases as well, and you may be able to retrieve the CID through /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/cid.

For example, on a Tattoo running 2.2, /sys/block/mmcblk0 is a soft link (established automatically by the system) to /sys/devices/platform/msm_sdcc.2/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:aaaa/block/mmcblk0.

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be `mmcblk0`, since there may be more than `mmcblk` device in some devices. If you are looking for particular CID, you should try looking in `mmcblk`*n* and if you are looking for CID of card where some file is, you should stat the file, and access the device via `/sys/dev/block/m:n/..` where `m:n` is the major and minor device number you got from stat. So e.g. `/sys/dev/block/179:1/..`. The `..` is to get from the partition to the card.

Comment: @JanHudec: Is it possible to stat the file from within an Android app to get the major/minor device numbers? I don't see `stat()` or anything similar in the Android APIs.

Comment: @LarsH, probably not. I use native code anyway, so I just call it there.

Answer (score 4):

There is api in android for getting sd card serial id. The method is called getFatVolumeId(String mountPoint), where "mountPoint" is sd card name (you can get this name by calling Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()). But getFatVolumeId is kindof hidden function (or forgotten), so you want to create package in your project named android.os and the class in it to reference the native method, to be able to call it:

```
package android.os;

public class FileUtils {
    public static native int getFatVolumeId(String mountPoint);
}
```

And the code is:

```
File SdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
int Serial = FileUtils.getFatVolumeId(SdCard.getName());
```

Also see the links

http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/1abd18435ba20a67?pli=1
http://markmail.org/message/rdl4bhwywywhhiau#query:+page:1+mid:rdl4bhwywywhhiau+state:results

Comment: Does not look either relevant or useful. It returns 32-bit integer, but CID is longer than that. Four times.

Comment: Although it doesn't give you the CID, it _is_ useful for uniquely identifying the current "external storage".

Comment: This doesn't answer the whole question, but it *does* give you the card's serial number, which is relevant and useful. I came here thinking I needed the CID, and learned that what I was really looking for was the serial number, which is only a part of the CID, and is easier to obtain. So thanks for this answer. Actually `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is not a reliable way to find the path of the microSD card, but that's a side issue.

Comment: On the other hand, since FileUtils and getFatVolumeId() are undocumented, there's no assurance that they will be present on any particular Android version or device. And indeed it's not there on mine (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20859031/423105).

Answer (score 3):

There is no Android API that can do this that I am aware of and for a general solution that is needed. To provide some background the SD card is connected to a hw-controller that is specific to the device platform. It is possible to read out the cid value from the linux /sys file system if you know your platform. The following snippet works on my droid (TI omap based platform) but not on Qualcomm MSM based platforms.

```
try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/sys/devices/platform/mmci-omap-hs.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/cid"));
        String sd_cid = input.readLine();
        Log.i("CID_APP", sd_cid);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CID_APP","Can not read SD-card cid");
    }
```

On a another platform the sys file we are looking for is different. It may even differ between different cards on the same platform since I was not able to test that. On MSM based devices the path would be something like /sys/devices/platform/msm_sdcc.1/mmc_host/...

Since we have this hardware dependence on reading out the SD-card CID there would have to be an update to the Android API:s that provides general access. This API would then have to be implemented by each device manufacturer to map to the correct sd card controller driver.

Comment: The path is different on different on each device.

Comment: Yes, that is why Samuel Tardieu's answer above is better, though not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this function too but could never get a home brewed solution.  I ended up finding a company that makes an SID reader.  Go to nexcopy.com and look in their SD or microSD duplicator section.  It can read up to 20 cards at a time.

Answer (score 2):

for `mmcblk0`, just write in shell as:

```
cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/cid 
2750485344303847307cf6851900b99b

cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/serial 
0x7cf68519
```

you can implement it in java easily.

ref:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/mmc/mmc-dev-attrs.txt
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt
http://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/sd-memory-card-faq/reading-sd-card-cid-serial-psn-internal-numbers/

Answer (score 1):

Even though the relatively ancient Palm OS and Windows Mobile OS devices are able to read the SD card ID, AFAIK Android devices aren't capable of doing that yet.  This is particularly troubling given the problems with the Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID discussed [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/53898e508fab44f6?hl=en).

Comment: They are perfectly capable of reading it. The driver exports in under `/sys` pseudo-filesystem. It is however somewhat tricky to find the right device there.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with the StorageManager.

Here is a sample-code:

```
final StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
final List<StorageVolume> storageVolumes = storageManager.getStorageVolumes();
final UserHandle user = android.os.Process.myUserHandle();
for (StorageVolume storageVolume : storageVolumes) {
     // "SDCARD" must be your sd-card name
     if (storageVolume.getDescription(activity).equals("SDCARD")){
        // the SD Card ID number
        return storageVolume.getUuid();
     }
 }
```

Comment: This gets the volume UUID, not the SD card ID (serial number) nor the CID.

Comment: This is what I was actually looking for... But this method will work on on Android Version >= 24, since StorageVolume are introduced in Android 24

Answer (score 0):

Building on Dinesh's answer...

Dinesh suggested looking in the directory
`/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:*/` (where * is a number) for the file named `cid`, which gives us the contents of the card's CID register. This is does work in many cases, and is a very helpful start.

But `mmc1` is not always the removable SD card. Sometimes, e.g. on a Motorola Droid Pro with Android API level 10, `mmc0` is the removable SD card, and `mmc1` is something else. I'm guessing that `mmc1`, when present, points to internal storage of some sort (possibly a non-removable microSD card). On a cheap Android tablet we tested, `mmc0` is the SD card and there is no `mmc1`.

So you can't just assume that `mmc1` is the SD card.

A glimmer of hope: It seems (so far) that by looking at the `type` file in the same directory as the `cid` file (e.g. `/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:0007/type`), we can determine which is which: a type value of `SD` indicates a removable SD card, while `MMC` is not.

However, that's just from testing on a few Android devices. I can't find any specifications about the contents of the `type` file, so if somebody else knows of relevant documentation, please let me know.

Of course, MMC and SD are just two different storage technology standards, and SD is backward-compatible with MMC. So it's not *necessarily* the case that type SD always corresponds to an external microSD card. It doesn't seem likely that `MMC` could indicate a microSD card at all (if the type field is populated accurately); but on the other hand, it's conceivable that a non-removable SD card could have type `SD`.

For further research: Does this approach work when an microSD card is connected via a USB adapter? My one test on this, with a tablet, had the USB-connected microSD card show up as `mmc1`, with type `SD`.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/990996/how-can-i-find-out-the-sys-class-or-sys-devices-entry-for-a-mounted-filesystem