# shell-finding the file that the result of the su command in it android

Tags: android, shell, su

after I rooted my mobile
and execute su
I wrote this command

```
os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/system/sd/temporary.txt\n");
```

it's working but I didn't find temprorary.txt
I search in sdcard and external card. the hole path is not exist.
is there any other memory to search in?
or any way to find this path?
or there is a problem in the command?

Comment: the sd card path seems not right. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976982/removable-storage-external-sdcard-path-by-manufacturers)

Comment: @JiangYD thank u for your notice. I see the link and I tried path 
/mnt/sdcard/external_sd  //!< Samsung galaxy family
.... my mobile is galaxy win dous but it dosen't work.
however this path work
/storage/extSdCard/

Comment: I find my path in my mobile while I'm opening my sdcard. It is written at the top of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try those :

```
/storage/sdcard1 //!< Motorola Xoom
/storage/extsdcard  //!< Samsung SGS3
/storage/sdcard0/external_sdcard  // user request
/mnt/extsdcard
/mnt/sdcard/external_sd  //!< Samsung galaxy family
/mnt/external_sd
/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1   //!< 4.4.2 on CyanogenMod S3
/removable/microsd              //!< Asus transformer prime
/mnt/emmc
/storage/external_SD            //!< LG
/storage/ext_sd                 //!< HTC One Max
/storage/removable/sdcard1      //!< Sony Xperia Z1
/data/sdext
/data/sdext2
/data/sdext3
/data/sdext4
```