# Exact difference and meaning of mmcblk0 and mmcblk1 in android?

Tags: android, linux, unix

I am working on an application where I need to detect the sd card id only when the card is present on the device. I have viewed and tried this link and it solves my problem:    [Android get id of SD Card programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063161/android-get-id-of-sd-card-programmatically)

But I didn't understand the exact meaning of mmcblk0 and mmcblk1, although I got that they are volume partitions of the memory.
Is anyone aware of that ? Please help if u know about the concept.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

Here, mmcblk0 is the internal NAND, and mmcblk1 is the external sd card.

Comment: thanks for answering but is it confirmed that mmcblk1 always points to the external sd card in any device ?