# Android - inserted SD card Unique ID

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

is there any way how to ensure, that user has in his phone same SD card, as he had, when the app was installed? Is there something as Unique ID of SD card?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe CID http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348643/how-to-read-the-sd-card-id-number