# What is the API to get the name of the SDCard in Android

Tags: android

On my NVidia shield I have an sdcard, which I can read and write to using :-

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

But when I refer to it in the UI, I would like to give it a more human name (my Shield names it "Samsung SD card").

How do I find this human readable replacement to

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

Comment: Something like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348643/how-to-read-the-sd-card-id-number/5191484#5191484)?

Comment: Use the above code mentioned by dhke to read the cid information of SD card and try to parse the CID to get the manufacture name. To prse the CID refer the below links. https://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/sd-memory-card-faq/reading-sd-card-cid-serial-psn-internal-numbers/ http://goughlui.com/2014/01/03/project-read-collect-decode-sd-card-csd-register-data/